How to convert the LLAMA weight into the Hugging face format?
First, when I try to follow to download the LLAMA weight and Tokenization.When I try to follow to do the Hugging face format process by this command:
python src/transformers/models/llama/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py \
    --input_dir /path/to/downloaded/llama/weights --model_size 7B --output_dir /output/path

The terminal display to me that:
Converting the tokenizer.
You are using the default legacy behaviour of the <class 'transformers.models.llama.tokenization_llama_fast.LlamaTokenizerFast'>. This is expected, and simply means that the `legacy` (previous) behavior will be used so nothing changes for you. If you want to use the new behaviour, set `legacy=False`. This should only be set if you understand what it means, and thoroughly read the reason why this was added as explained in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/24565 - if you loaded a llama tokenizer from a GGUF file you can ignore this message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/convert_slow_tokenizer.py", line 1636, in convert_slow_tokenizer
    ).converted()
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/convert_slow_tokenizer.py", line 1533, in converted
    tokenizer = self.tokenizer()
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/convert_slow_tokenizer.py", line 1526, in tokenizer
    vocab_scores, merges = self.extract_vocab_merges_from_model(self.vocab_file)
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/convert_slow_tokenizer.py", line 1502, in extract_vocab_merges_from_model
    bpe_ranks = load_tiktoken_bpe(tiktoken_url)
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tiktoken/load.py", line 144, in load_tiktoken_bpe
    contents = read_file_cached(tiktoken_bpe_file, expected_hash)
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tiktoken/load.py", line 63, in read_file_cached
    contents = read_file(blobpath)
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tiktoken/load.py", line 21, in read_file
    with blobfile.BlobFile(blobpath, "rb") as f:
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/blobfile/_ops.py", line 393, in BlobFile
    return default_context.BlobFile(
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/blobfile/_context.py", line 894, in BlobFile
    f = io.FileIO(path, mode=mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/downloaded/llama/weights/tokenizer.model'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ploy/transformers/./src/transformers/models/llama/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 502, in write_tokenizer
    tokenizer = tokenizer_class(input_tokenizer_path)
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/tokenization_llama_fast.py", line 157, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py", line 138, in __init__
    fast_tokenizer = convert_slow_tokenizer(self, from_tiktoken=True)
  File "/home/ploy/.conda/envs/anomalygpt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/convert_slow_tokenizer.py", line 1638, in convert_slow_tokenizer
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Converting from Tiktoken failed, if a converter for SentencePiece is available, provide a model path with a SentencePiece tokenizer.model file.Currently available slow->fast convertors: ['AlbertTokenizer', 'BartTokenizer', 'BarthezTokenizer', 'BertTokenizer', 'BigBirdTokenizer', 'BlenderbotTokenizer', 'CamembertTokenizer', 'CLIPTokenizer', 'CodeGenTokenizer', 'ConvBertTokenizer', 'DebertaTokenizer', 'DebertaV2Tokenizer', 'DistilBertTokenizer', 'DPRReaderTokenizer', 'DPRQuestionEncoderTokenizer', 'DPRContextEncoderTokenizer', 'ElectraTokenizer', 'FNetTokenizer', 'FunnelTokenizer', 'GPT2Tokenizer', 'HerbertTokenizer', 'LayoutLMTokenizer', 'LayoutLMv2Tokenizer', 'LayoutLMv3Tokenizer', 'LayoutXLMTokenizer', 'LongformerTokenizer', 'LEDTokenizer', 'LxmertTokenizer', 'MarkupLMTokenizer', 'MBartTokenizer', 'MBart50Tokenizer', 'MPNetTokenizer', 'MobileBertTokenizer', 'MvpTokenizer', 'NllbTokenizer', 'OpenAIGPTTokenizer', 'PegasusTokenizer', 'Qwen2Tokenizer', 'RealmTokenizer', 'ReformerTokenizer', 'RemBertTokenizer', 'RetriBertTokenizer', 'RobertaTokenizer', 'RoFormerTokenizer', 'SeamlessM4TTokenizer', 'SqueezeBertTokenizer', 'T5Tokenizer', 'UdopTokenizer', 'WhisperTokenizer', 'XLMRobertaTokenizer', 'XLNetTokenizer', 'SplinterTokenizer', 'XGLMTokenizer', 'LlamaTokenizer', 'CodeLlamaTokenizer', 'GemmaTokenizer', 'Phi3Tokenizer']

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ploy/transformers/./src/transformers/models/llama/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 601, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ploy/transformers/./src/transformers/models/llama/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 576, in main
    write_tokenizer(
  File "/home/ploy/transformers/./src/transformers/models/llama/convert_llama_weights_to_hf.py", line 504, in write_tokenizer
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to instantiate tokenizer. Please, make sure you have sentencepiece and protobuf installed.

From above, which is the problem, so how can I do it?
How to solve this problem or If every one used to face this please tell me the process each step by step.

Did you try what the error message says already? Ensuring that sentencepiece and protobuf are installed? Use pip install sentencepiece protobuf.

yes, I have already installed "pip install sentencepiece protobuf"
